# Need to see exact query execution in Oracle ADF

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-adf

I am using Oracle ADF in Oracle Jdeveloper 11g.
In the application i have a search screen which will go through records as per the search values given.

The search screen uses a view object. My requirement is to check out which final query is being executed on the DB after all the dynamic creation. what all parameters do i need to change to get the same.

also My application logs are at FINEST Level.

Please help

Comment: Are you using EclipseLink to access the database?

Comment: I am not sure what Oracle ADF uses for connecting to Database but i think its not EclipseLink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this one a few weeks back.
Works like a charm.
http://huysmansitt.blogspot.be/2012/09/adf-bc-logging.html

Comment: it is good but i am not able to find the property mentioned in the logging.xml. Did you find the exact steps..??

Answer (score 0):

> log4jdbc is a Java JDBC driver that can log SQL and/or JDBC calls (and optionally SQL timing information) for other JDBC drivers using the Simple Logging Facade For Java (SLF4J) logging system.

See: https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/

Comment: other than applying a new set of libraries, is there any setting or any other way...i am not in development phase. its the bug fixing one and i cannot update the application with new libraries..

Comment: That's not an application library. You can configure your Connection-/JDBC Pool to use this JDBC Proxy outside of your application (-archive).

Answer (score 0):

Try running the `WLS` in `debugger mode` and set the level of logging to `finest` by

`Right Click on Integrated Weblogic Server --> Configure Diagnostic Logging --> Set  Root Logger level to finest`.

It should work.

Comment: as i already told in the question, the logging is already to finest level

Comment: Did you try running the application module if the query is  displayed?

Comment: yes i did..that is why i asked the question on this forum, because i couldn't get it in Jdev